# How can I delete /usr/bin/python3 (older version of Python)

Tags: python

I used to use Python 3.10.4 but I installed Python 3.8.9, Python 3.8.10 to use GPU on my 2019 MBP (Mac OS Monterey 12.4) but it did not work.

So I tried to uninstall all of my old versions of Python (3.8.9 and 3.8.10) but when I go to VSCode and select kernel for my new Jupyter Notebook file, the list shows Python 3.8.9 and 3.10.4.

[image]

And when I go to my Terminal app and I do not find 3.8.9.

[image]

Can you help me with this problem showing old version of Python?

Comment: Sorry this is my first time to post images together...

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: @ItagakiFumihiko: I am using macOS Monterey 12.4

Comment: @javaIsHard: That's a bit intentional. Please don't post pictures of text, just post the text itself.

Comment: @MSalters: sorry this is my first time to post pictures, I'll try that next time. Thank you!

Comment: Whether or not this is your first post, edit your question to include text formatted as code instead of images.

Answer (score 3):

The python stored inside `/usr/local/bin` is a python installed by you, and it may be removed or updated.
In other side, python stored in `/usr/bin` is a **default** python that comes with macOS from beginning (you didn't install it)

macOS trying to use default (protected from changes) version when running some python dependable system applications. If you remove default version, that may break some OS features.

It is possible to remove default applications inside `/usr/bin` after turning off [SIP](https://www.macworld.com/article/672057/how-to-turn-off-rootless-sip-or-system-integrity-protection-in-os-x.html), but I don't recommend to do that

Comment: Is the default python version for Mac 3.8.9???

Comment: Do you see any problem here? [(Version)](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691403)

Comment: thank you... I should just keep the default version there. And is there a way to hide Python 3.8.9 in my VSCode python kernel selection list?

Comment: `And is there a way to hide Python 3.8.9` → Not sure if it possible. What is exact problem to see default version in list? Just don't select it `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Defining the user location's Python in my script allowed me to get cron to execute it with the correct Python (whereas it was resolving `/usr/bin/env` to the default location).

Answer (score 0):

From my limited experience with mac os, it's possible that when you [uninstalled](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-uninstall-python) Python you didn't change it's PATH so when you call Python, you call a legacy version.

As stated in this [guide](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-add-python-to-the-path-variable-in-mac).

- `which python` will show you the path of your installed python. Copy it.
- `sudo nano /etc/paths` will ask you for the password and open a text editor
  copy the Python path in it.

try it

Comment: Python 3.8.9 still shows in my VSCode when I select kernel for my python project...

Comment: I'm quite sure it show the most recent interpreters. You can change interpreter settings following this guide. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_work-with-python-interpreters